# Calling a function: NameError need to define

Tags: python, function

How can I define userMiles outside the function to be able to call it without putting userMiles = float(input()) outside the function?

```
def MilesToLaps(userMiles):
    """Convert miles to laps."""
    userMiles = float(input())
    userLaps = userMiles/0.25
    return userLaps


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MilesToLaps(userMiles))
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem.  You specifically pass that value *into* the function, which means that you *must* have defined it outside the function.  Then, the first thing your function code does is to destroy that very value.  You *seem* to be confused about passing values to and from a function.  If so, this would suggest another run through your tutorial on the topic, rather than Stack Overflow ... maybe ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after here, so Ill try multiple answers and hopefully one of them will meet your needs.

When you put a variable in the brackets when you define a function, you are passing through data to that function, so essentially you could just move one line outside the function.

```
def MilesToLaps(userMiles):
    """Convert miles to laps."""
    userLaps = userMiles/0.25
    return userLaps


userMiles = float(input())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MilesToLaps(userMiles))
```

Should you not want to pass any argument to the function you could use **global variables**.

```
def MilesToLaps():
    """Convert miles to laps."""

    global userMiles

    userLaps = userMiles/0.25
    return userLaps


userMiles = float(input())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(MilesToLaps())
```

I hope I've given you the answer you're searching for or at least given you insight into a different approach you could use to tackle this problem.

All the best.